# Compilation failure cannot access Terminable java

Tags: java

I have the following error "Compilation failure cannot access Terminable java" when compile my proyect with maven, after an upgrade library

Update version dependency 2.3 to 2.11

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.11.2</version>                   
 </dependency>
```

Comment: What's the error? Sorry, couldn't understand your question.

Comment: hi I update the question and also de solution

Answer (score 0):

Just validate if you have dependencies declare in the POM and also updte them

In my case. when also update dependencies of my library log4j-core in the Pom.xml file:

is needed to update the following dependencies

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
</dependency>  
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```